# Argument evaluation order

Tags: python, assignment-operator, evaluation

Is the python argument evaluation order defined behaviour? And is the order of evaluation the same as the appear in the source-code?

Consider this example:

```py
print(f"{(a:=1)}", f"{a=}",  f"{(a:=2)}", f"{a=}")  # print 1
print(f"{a=}")                                      # print 2
```

Is the first statement guaranteed to print `"1 a=1 2 a=2"`?
And is the second guaranteed to print `"a=2"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, python expressions are evaluated left to right. This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order).